# De Que Forma Alternar Entre Valores Da Tabela

Tags: javascript, table

## Código

```
<table border="1px" width="33%">

 <th bgcolor="silver">Trocar de Posição</th>

 <tr>

  <td id="cel_01">Texto 1</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>

  <td id="cel_02">Texto 2</td>

 </tr>

</table>
```

## Exemplo

**Antes**

Texto 1

Texto 2

[image]

**Depois**

Texto 2

Texto 1

[image]

> Ao clicar no Botão *"Troca"*, **Alternar Linha** *Texto 1* para *Texto 2* e vice-versa.

Comment: Queres mudar com a célula que está por cima, por baixo ou ordenar todas de uma maneira e poder inverter essa ordem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso faz o que você deseja:

**Utilizando JQuery**

```js
            $("button").click(function(){
                var text_01 = $("#cell-01").html();
                var text_02 = $("#cell-02").html();

                $("#cell-01").html(text_02);
                $("#cell-02").html(text_01);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="cell-01">A Text 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="cell-02">B Text 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button>Change</button>
```

Puro JavaScript

```js
            function changeHTML(){
                var text_01 = document.getElementById('cell-01').innerHTML;
                var text_02 = document.getElementById('cell-02').innerHTML;


                document.getElementById('cell-01').innerHTML = text_02;
                document.getElementById('cell-02').innerHTML = text_01;
            };
```

```html
        <table border="1px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="cell-01">A Text 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="cell-02">B Text 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button onclick="changeHTML()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Adicionei a mesma lógica com puto JS ;) Espero ter ajudado.